# Fonts won't change in the output

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been trying to change my fonts with Google Fonts in my HTML / CSS, but it keeps on remaining at its default font. I've googled everywhere and still the same. Could there be something wrong with my code?

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="myscripts.js">
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="script/script.js">
    </script>
    <title>The Story Maker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Story Maker</h1>
    <p>Fabricate a comical, romantic, jovial, or even petrifying story with this story maker! Let your imagination and creativity loose!</p>
    <div class="navigation">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Create A Story</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
          <li>Donate</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="showContainer">

        <div class="imageContainer" id="img_1">
          <img src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/pro-ww-wordpress/libre/uploads/sites/2/2018/03/08091927/Disney-Meet-80cr.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            The Tale of the Snow White
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer" id="img_2">
          <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/51c436b44f5ec312055a7ed22cc6dd2b/tumblr_osyb8fvLA81thrhjso1_400.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            The Horror Tale of the Dolls
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer" id="img_3">
          <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/4dca7a847bd3fe0dae5bcfefddf850fb/tumblr_phrz8lNkHI1qcpptho1_640.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            The Romantic Tale of Sara and John
          </div>
        <div class="imageContainer" id="img_3">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1c/f5/a0/1cf5a0e20fdd174956031fff77376f17.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            The Adventures of Felicity
          </div>
        </div>


    <div class="navButton" id="previous">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="navButton" id="next">&#10095;</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My css code:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

I even tried using a font like Arial and nothing happens. No change in the output.

Comment: Unrelated (**hopefully**) but you have invalid HTML which will render unexpected results. You need _two_ closing `div`s before your `</body>` tag & `id="img_3"` is declared _twice_ which is illegal in HTML (id's must be unique).

Comment: Welcome to SO Nadia. I tried copy pasting your HTML and CSS. It worked without any modifications. Perhaps you have a typo in your CSS? Try pressing `F12` on a Chrome browser and check your Console for any errors.

Comment: @EGC noted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kathir Hi! It is completely my mistake. I deleted my css folder and made a new one, but then I realised I didn't link my href to my css folder. It should've been     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" /> instead of just     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />. After that, everything worked fine. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it internally, maybe?

```
<style>
h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Or check if you named your css file styles.css?

Comment: I named it style.css, does it matter if it has a 's' or no?

Comment: It does matter. In the `<head>` of your code, it says:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`. 
`href` is the address of the css code, so you need your file to be styles.css.
Then you should be able to have a separate css file. Or you can just change `href="styles.css"` to `href="style.css" `

Comment: I changed it to styles.css, nothing happens. Is there a possible way for me not to have to do it internally?

Comment: You changed the file name and the <link> in head and your file name are the same?

Comment: Yes I did, I changed the file name to styles.css, matching the href.

Comment: That's strange. Are they in the same folder?

Comment: I think there was a problem with my css file. I deleted it and created a new one, and now it works. Thanks for helping btw!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, this must be a problem with your browser. These are the browsers that support Google Fonts API:

- Google Chrome - version 4.249.4+
- Mozilla Firefox - version: 3.5+
- Apple Safari - version 3.1+
- Opera - version 10.5+
- Microsoft Internet Explorer - version 6+

Comment: All of these seem to be in check. Thanks though!